# Using bash pipe instead of select statement

Tags: sql, linux, bash, shell

I was wondering if it is possible to use a bash pipe instead of a select statement on a `tab seperated value(tsv) - file`

My tsv file has the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE movies (title VARCHAR, full_name VARCHAR, type VARCHAR, ep_num VARCHAR, suspended BOOLEAN, year INT);
```

If I want to retrieve:

`How many movies were produced in 2013?`

I would say in `sql`: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM movies WHERE year='2013';`

However, how would I say that in a pipe bash(using `cat`, `grep` or `wc`)? Is this even possible?

I really appreciate your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use e.g. [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk '$(NF)==2013' input.tsv
```

This will print every line where the last field is `2013`.

If you only want to count the movies, you can do:

```
awk '$(NF)==2013 { count+=1 }; END { print count }' input.tsv
```

If you want to use [grep](/questions/tagged/grep):

```
grep '2013$' input.tsv | uniq -c
```